# WCF, containers in DataContract

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontract

I need to pass some container of objects to WCF call

```
[DataContract]
class Foo
{
 // other fields omited

 [DataMember]
 public List<Foo> MyList;
}
```

Is it OK for serialization? If not what are my options?

Comment: I mean if List<Foo> MyList will be sucessfully serialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok but the resulting type will be an array and not a list. I'm partial to using array in the contract just to make sure I don't try to use it as list someplace else.

Comment: How do you mean list will become array? Pls clarify. Thanks.

Comment: You can adjust the proxy generator to emit either arrays or lists. I Think arrays are default though.

Comment: Would changing it to IList<Foo> sort that?

Comment: You can change the defaults in you service ref. configuration. See http://dotnet.org.za/hiltong/archive/2008/05/21/using-generic-list-lt-t-gt-from-wcf-services.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It will successfuly serialize even if you don't apply DataContract. The only condition is that all used types in serialization have parameterless constructor (even private will do), e.g:

```
List<T> - already has it.
Foo - have it by default.
```